# Semantic zoom in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, semantic-zoom

I've got an app with a dynamically populated pivot control which works quite well, but lately I find I have too many items in my pivot to scroll through effectively. I want to implement semantic zoom like the photo viewer app does - i.e. when someone pinches on the app it should zoom out to a faster scrolling view, or possibly an entirely different view (maybe a list)

I've searched online (and here on stackoverflow.com) for 'semantic zoom windows phone' but I only get hits for windows 8 semantic zoom. is there a different name for this feature in wp8? How do I go about implementing it?

Comment: Semantic zoom is not available in WP8, possibly you will have to design such a control yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pivot design guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202919%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) specify that

> Apps should minimize the number of pivot pages (four pages or fewer)

So if you have that many items in you pivot, that probably mean that Pivot is not the appropriate control for you.

If you still want to create a semantic zoom like experience you could try to do it yourself by using the windows phone toolkit GestureListener and scaling the view using RenderTransform.
Here is an article describing the GestureListener:
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-gestureservice-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api

Comment: The app launches with only four items in the pivot, but the user can edit those items and add more. In testing I've found a high number becomes unwieldy

Comment: Maybe past a certain number of items you should just move to a two level list.